# npm install error - No Xcode or CLT version detected?

Tags: angular, npm-install, package.json, macos-catalina

"no receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.cltools_executables' found at '/'"

Above error is thrown while running 'npm install' for an angular 9 project in VS Code bash terminal for MacOS (Catalina)

Package.json dependencies:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
```

Comment: Yes! This has been messing me up all day!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got this working by following the steps below:

- Find out the path for the command line tools
  `xcode-select --print-path`
- Delete command line tools directory ( Directory path can be retrieved from the above step )
  `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
- Run this to re-install
  `xcode-select --install`

Post this, 'npm install' should run successfully on VS Code in MacOS bash terminal.

Comment: `sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select --print-path)` just to be sure you copy it right

Comment: this does not work with Big Sur and Xcode 12.5