# Cannot install Gulp-sass on macOS Big Sur 11.4

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

when starting Gulp today, I got the message that gulp-sass was not installed:

> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'

Apparently some node_modules have been removed.

So I tried to remove and reinstall it like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620314/14331711):

> npm install gulp-sass

But got errors, so i changed node 16 with nvm through node 15.

Python2 and [xcode is installed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63300340/14331711)

But it doesnt work and i get the following errors:

```
~/Developer ❯ nvm use 15                                                                                                                                                                                 
Now using node v15.14.0 (npm v7.7.6)

~/Developer ❯ npm install gulp-sass                                                                                                                                                                          17:17:40
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /Users/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin/node /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 15.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '15.14.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "15.14.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 15.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 15.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/MYUSERNAME/.node-gyp/15.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/MYUSERNAME/.node-gyp/15.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/MYUSERNAME/.node-gyp/15.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin/node" "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/MYUSERNAME/Developer/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/MYUSERNAME/.npm/_logs/2021-06-07T15_17_46_462Z-debug.log
```

I did uninstall/reinstall Nodejs, but that didn't help.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it helps to correct the path to my installed command-line tools (CTL) with the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

and use [gulp-dart-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65050165/14331711)